# Twitter app on ios 4.3 request token issue on device

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I m new to ios application.Currently i m working on twitter application for ios 4.3 in which i m facing error below.My app works fine on simulator but does not works on iPad/iPhone.I m using code from this link "http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/"

Error :
"Whoa there!.The request token for this page is invalid.It may have already been used or expired because it is too old.Please go back to site or application that sent you here."

Please help to sort the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `kOAuthConsumerKey` and `kOAuthConsumerSecret` value if those are valid as per your application on Twitter account.